# After uninstalling rvm I get the following when opening a new Terminal session

Tags: macos, rvm

After uninstalling rvm I get the following when opening a new Terminal session:

```
Last login: Tue Mar 26 22:39:30 on ttys000
-bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
~\ $
```

How do I determine where that comes from?

```
-bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

I installed rvm by running this installer: http://railsinstaller.org/ on a Mac with Mountain Lion. I ran the uninstaller for that package. That was supposed to unsintall rvm, but there are some traces left. I won't be using rvm after all because of some openssl issues when installing rubies with it.

Comment: Look in your ~/.bash_profile and remove the line referring to rvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for `/etc/profile` for:

```
source /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

if this is the case then please report a bug for Railsinstaller: https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-nix/issues

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! I'll create an issue!